# Forms authentication doesnt work when a fully qualified domain name is used

Tags: c#, .net, forms-authentication

Forms authentication doesnt work when a fully qualified domain name is used

localhost works
computername works
computername.fullyqualify.com does not work.
IP address works.

It ends up going in a loop between redirecting between the login and the main page.

It is almost as though the cookie is not being written.

Is there an IIS or active directory setting that I need to change here?

Comment: Hi, does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453677/single-sign-on-with-forms-authentication

Comment: Does the `<forms>` element in your Web.config have a `domain` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is DNS' job to resolve FQDNs to IPs. From IIS you specify what IP to use, from a pool of IPs assigned to your Web Server, with which site amongt many hosted on your Web Server.

Check if you have correct Canonical Name record (CNAME) entries in you AD for the desired IPs.

Also ensure that it's replicated to all DNS servers if you have load balancing in AD.

Comment: would this cause the web.page to come up... but for forms authentication itself not to work?