# Single Sign on in multiple ASP MVC 3 applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, single-sign-on

I have a solution that has two applications. Is it possible to make the user sign in only once?

For example, in the main application I do authentication like this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(ContactFound.ContaLogin, model.RememberMe);
```

And I put this code in the `web.config` file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms 
    loginUrl="~/Account/LogIn" 
    defaultUrl="~/Account/LogOn" 
    timeout="15"
  />      
</authentication>
```

What should I add, so that, when the user is logged in, in the main application we don't ask him to log in again when he connect to the second application?

Comment: Are both applications going to be hosted on the same server/domain?

Comment: Yes, they will be hosted in the same server, but is there a difference ?

Comment: Yup - cross domain would be much more difficult, because cookies cannot be used from a different domain. Your case should be fairly straight on, because you do not have that problem. (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10073566/11963)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are going to host both applications at the same address, it should be easily possible by setting the `<machineKey>` (web.config) to the same value for both applications. After that, you should automatically be logged in to one application after logging in to the other.

Further reading:

- [Single Sign On (SSO) for cross-domain ASP.NET applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic) (see How authentication works in multiple ASP.NET sites under the same domain)
- [machineKey Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w8h3skw9.aspx)
- [Single Sign On with Forms Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2453677/11963)