# Multiple Forms Authentication Applications with Active Directory and Single Sign on

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, forms-authentication, single-sign-on

I have a requirement that I can't seem to figure out mainly because I don't have much experience with single sign on. I am currently using Forms Authentication with Active Directory on 3 to 4 web applications. My requirement is to have a "central" login. If a user has access to App 1 and App 2, then they are allowed to see those two apps. If a user has access to App 2 and App 4, then they can only see those two applications. I have recently set up an Active Directory Role Provider with the help of this [link here.](http://slalomdev.blogspot.com/2008/08/active-directory-role-provider.html)

I have also looked into the single sign on options on the internet. So far, I have come across a few that looked pretty good. However, I think I'm running into trouble because I'm using Active Directory. [This one here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27576/Single-Sign-on-in-ASP-NET-and-Other-Platforms) works very well for the basic Forms Authentication, but I'm unable to tweak it with AD properly.

I then moved on to try a [cookie solution here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/74631/Single-Sign-on-SSO-Using-Cookie-in-asp-net). I'm able to view the cookie on App 2 but I have to sign in again to be allowed to view the complete application.

I have even found solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453677/single-sign-on-with-forms-authentication) but I can't seem to find an example to do it the way I need to. I have found many different techniques on how to do SSO but I'm having no luck and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

One option that I thought of was making a separate application that handles login, and directs them to a "Dashboard" where I can then give them access to applications based on their groups in the AD. Would this be a feasible solution?

If any other information is needed, please let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using FormsAuth when you are operating in an AD environment? Do you have external users that you need to support? Is the app always running while "online" or connected to the network?

In the past when we had to control permissions to certain apps, we did it for each app specifically. This was largely driven by business rules as each application had someone that administered the permissions explicitly. ex: We would have a landing page and anyone could know about App2, but you had to be apart of a specific AD group to access it. To gain access to App2 you had to email or autonotify the App2 Administrator

If you want a centralized repository and control permissions of all of your apps from 1 location where a group of admins have the domain knowledge for all of the apps - your dashboard idea sounds ideal.

You shouldn't have to worry about any auth issues if you switch it over to WindowsAuth and use AD groups to manage permissions.

Comment: We are using Forms Auth mainly because it looks better than the Windows Auth, haha. All apps are on to the same domain and as of right now, we are controlling permissions per app. We are using the AD account as just a login so we don't have to store any passwords in SQL Server. However, we are using SQL roles to deny access to certain parts of each application. As you can tell, this is not ideal, works fine, but not ideal for up keep. So we are moving from the SQL roles, to the AD roles with a single sign on.