# Advice: MVC plugins / separate widgets architecture

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, multiple-projects, razorgenerator

I am building a project with one main Web Project which acts as the main user experience and several other Web Projects which act as plugins/ widgets to be viewed inside the main website (Often as a part of a larger page on the main website).

I am basically seeking advice on the best way to architect this.

I have so far tried the following:

1) one main web project and a seperate project for each plugin each with a seperate domain. The plugins would then be inserted in to the main website with an iFrame. 
The problem I encountered was with authentication. I have forms authentication on the main project and could not get the plugins to read from the same login cookie meaning they each required loggin in before they would work. See this question I asked: [Authentication over multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705119/authentication-over-multiple-projects?noredirect=1#comment74538499_43705119)

I also don't like using iFrames.

2) I tried using RazorGenerator to embed the views and that way they become a part of the project and so I wouldn't need to use an iFrame or worry about multi project authentication.

This seemed like a good solution but I couldn't get the static content to come across.

I found [this](http://www.geekality.net/2014/11/04/output-embedded-resources-into-razor-views/) which seems a bit hacky and [this](https://codesnob.wordpress.com/2014/03/06/mvc-area-in-an-external-assembly/) which didn't work in various situations.

Can anyone advise me on how you would go about doing this or if there is a way to get one of the above two solutions working?

Comment: We really need more details about either problem :(  For each, could you be more specific about a) your code, b) the use case, and c) the exact error?

Comment: Im not sure what more details to provide? The error for the static content is I have no idea how to access it from my main project. I can get the cshtml files into my main project using RazorGenerator but not the css or js files. 

The Use Case?

Answer (score 0):

From your perspective, I'm sure you're being completely clear.  Unfortunately, although I understand "conceptually" what you're trying to do ... I really don't have a clue which "technical details" I'm failing to ask you about, much less "what, exactly is going wrong".

So we're at kind of an impasse.  The ironic part is that if you were to explain to the level of detail I'm asking for ... you'd probably understand the problem yourself, and wouldn't have needed to ask in the first place :(

SUGGESTIONS:

1. There's absolutely nothing wrong with breaking your solution into separate projects.  In fact, that's absolutely the RIGHT thing to do - it's actually "best practice".
2. There's absolutely nothing wrong with using "components" (I'm using the word in the "generic" sense) whose implementation happens to reside outside of your project.  That, too, is "best practice".
3. I tend to put all the "UI-related" stuff into the SAME project.  Other subprojects partition the application into other *functional* parts.  For example for application "ABC", I have one solution and seven projects:

`ABC .sln
  + CodeGen.EF
  + ABC.BLL
  + ABC.DAL
  + ABC.DB
  + ABC.Entity
  + ABC.Web
    <= "Scripts/", and all my Views, Controllers and View-related Models are here
  + ABC.Common
    <= Application-independent stuff goes here`

'Hope that helps ... at least a little...

Comment: OK so Currently I am using RazorGenerator to make two Web Projects available to my main web project. Each individual module (Web Project) has Controllers, Helper Classes, Views, Javascript files and Style sheets. 

Using Razor Generator I have Got access to the views (Including the Layouts) and by referencing the modules I have access to the serverside stuff. 

My problem is I don't know how to get access to the CSS and Javascript.

Comment: Uh - put *.js in your project's "/Scripts", your *.css in your project's "Content/", and "include" them in your .cshtml? PS: Are you using MVC 4.x or 5, with IIS ... or are you using "some other version"? And are you using MSVS for your "builds" ... or are you doing "something else"?  If you just use the standard MSVS tooling in a standard way ... everything should "just work".