# Azure Front Door Service Blocking Azure AD SSO

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-front-door

I've got an ASP.Net MVC Web app that I've migrated from Forms Authentication to SSO with Azure AD (OpenID connect) that is working fine locally and on stage environment, until I enable Azure Front Door and then the callback from Azure AD SSO is blocked.

Azure Front Door is set to Prevention mode and is using the default managed rule set (DefaultRuleSet_1.0)

Have I got some configuration wrong somewhere?  Thanks.

Comment: That's interesting! Is it possible that it could be another issue with the forms? Can you share some of your configuration?

Comment: Troubleshooting SSO: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins

Comment: Forms SSO: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453677/single-sign-on-with-forms-authentication